# Get record number of a form in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I get the record number in a form?

Can I use it in sql queries?
[image]

Edit: I have a report that gets its data from form by a sql query, the problem is when I have multiple records the report shows the first record of table

Answer (score 1):

You should never rely on something that is not part of the data itself. For each of your tables, you can have an ID column as an autoinc integer value (primary key).

Comment: Yeah, I have an ID in my table but I get my data from the form and when I have multiple records the result of the query always shows the first record

Comment: What do you mean? How does your table structure and query look like?

Answer (score 0):

use an unbounded text box (from your table or query) with the source being

```
=[CurrentRecord]
```

Add a field as such

```
SELECT A.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AssetsExtended where A.ID>=ID) AS RowNum
FROM AssetsExtended AS A
ORDER BY A.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me #Error in textBox

Comment: @AliTheOne, more info on what you tried would be helpful to get the error.  Open your Table1, on the create ribbon, click form. In the form layout tools drag a textbox into the form, and change the control source in the property sheet data tab to =[CurrentRecord].

Comment: Thank you, the record number doesn't help neither, I found another way and it worked fine

Comment: @AliTheOne, I have no idea what that response means.  You should include your workaround as an answer in that case.